# Pass props to reduxForm

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is it possible to pass down props to reduxForm, something like this:

```
export default (props) => reduxForm({
  form: props.form, // Want to make redux page to be generic
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  validate: props.validate
})(WizardFormFirstPage)
```

Comment: The `form` config needs to be a string, the identifier of your form. The rest of the question does not make much sense. Please edit your question to clarify what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just do

```
const FormComponent = reduxForm({
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(Component)
```

and then

```
 <FormComponent form="formName" validate={validateFn}/>
 <FormComponent form="formName2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but if you want to pass props to a component wrapped by a HOC, you can do it the same way as with any other component.

```
export default reduxForm({ ...config})(WrappedComponent);
```

```
import MyForm from "./wherever";

...

<MyForm prop={propHere}/>
```

And you can use the prop any way you need to within the component, including in conjunction with Redux Form functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is unfortunately not what I meant. I want to use the prop inside the reduxForm(...)

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish that you cannot by incorporating the prop from the component?